# How to get the result by parsing the log after executing the contract? How can I get the execution result?

Tags: web3js, contract-development, transactions, contract-design

How to get the result by parsing the log after executing the contract? How can I get the execution result ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you don't.

You get what's in the log from the log.

Other contracts can get the result, but you can't sign a transaction that changes the state and also get the result.

Have a look here: https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the receipt.                                                                                                                                   {
  blockHash: '0x30127276daa98740a2ed0bcbf47f9a345e44e766751ec2889e93482e784064c5',
  blockNumber: 6692373,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 58199,
  from: '0x8e0f4a1f3c0dbea0c73684b49ae4ad02789b3ec4',
  gasUsed: 27584,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: '0x.....',
  status: true,
  to: '0xc2500c2a90dc6eece516582caca5b006d425e1ff',
  transactionHash: '0x....',
  transactionIndex: 1
}

Comment: I want to parse the receipt.logs, but it fail when I use this code.                                                                       const abi = _.find(item => (item.name == "LoginEvent") && item.type == "event");
           const eventJsonInterface = _.find(
      contract._jsonInterface,
      o => (o.name === 'LoginEvent' || o.name === 'CreateUser') && o.type === 'event',
     )
     const log = _.find(
      receipt.logs,
      l => l.topics.includes(eventJsonInterface.signature)
     )
     let de = ABI.decodeLog(eventJsonInterface.inputs, log.data, log.topics.slice(1))